# Liquify filter/iwarp

Tags: algorithm, image-processing

I'm trying to build something like the Liquify filter in Photoshop. I've been reading through image distortion code but I'm struggling with finding out what will create similar effects. The closest reference I could find was the iWarp filter in Gimp but the code for that isn't commented at all.

I've also looked at places like ImageMagick but they don't have anything in this area

Any pointers or a description of algorithms would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, I successfully implemented Liquify in [Photopea.com](https://www.Photopea.com) (press Filter - Liquify). It took me two weeks of expermienting, but the final algorithm turned out to be quite simple.

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me if I make this sound a little simplistic, I'm not sure how much you know about gfx programming or even what techniques you're using (I'd do it with HLSL myself).

The way I would approach this problem is to generate a texture which contains offsets of x/y coordinates in the r/g channels. Then the output colour of a pixel would be:
Texture inputImage
Texture distortionMap
colour(x,y) = inputImage(x + distortionMap(x, y).R, y + distortionMap(x, y).G)
(To tell the truth this isn't quite right, using the colours as offsets directly means you can only represent positive vectors, it's simple enough to subtract 0.5 so that you can represent negative vectors)

Now the only problem that remains is how to generate this distortion map, which is a different question altogether (any image would generate a distortion of some kind, obviously, working on a proper liquify effect is quite complex and I'll leave it to someone more qualified).

Answer (score 0):

I think liquefy works by altering a grid.
Imagine each pixel is defined by its location on the grid.
Now when the user clicks on a location and move the mouse he's changing the grid location.
The new grid is again projected into the 2D view able space of the user.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this tutorial](http://geekofficedog.blogspot.com/2015/01/liquify-effect-hello-swirl-2.html) about a way to implement the liquify filter with Javascript. Basically, in the tutorial, the effect is done transforming the pixel Cartesian coordinates `(x, y)` to Polar coordinates `(r, α)` and then applying `Math.sqrt` on `r`.